# Java Stream: How to Sum Value If Element Already Exists

Tags: java, java-stream, maps

Given the following key...

```
private class PositionKey {
    String assetId;
    String currencyId;
}
```

... I need to create a `Map<PositionKey, BigDecimal>`, where if a given key does not exist, then a new entry shall be added, otherwise, if a given key already exists, then its values shall be increased. Here below is my attempt:

```
public Map<PositionKey, BigDecimal> getMap(final Long portfolioId) {

    final Map<PositionKey, BigDecimal> map = new HashMap<>();

    // getPositions() returns all the positions associated with the given portfolio
    return getPositions(portfolioId).stream()
        .collect(
            toMap(
                position ->
                    new PositionKey(
                        position.getAssetId(),
                        position.geCurrencyId()),
                position -> position.geValue(),
                (newValue, oldValue) -> oldValue != null ? oldValue.add(newValue) : newValue,
                () -> map));
}
```

What I dislike in my implementation above, is the fact that I create the `Map` before streaming the positions. Is there a better way to implement this? Thank you very much.

Comment: Just use `HashMap::new` instead of `() -> map`.

Comment: There is, by the way, no reason for performing a `null`-check in the merge function. The assumption that the first argument is a “new value” and the second an “old value”, is wrong anyway. The merge function will only be invoked if there are at least two elements for the same key; the collector will not invoke the function with `null`. So you can simply use `BigDecimal::add` as merge function. Unless, your `getValue` method can return `null`, but in that case you’d have to check *both* arguments for `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case if you have **no** specific requirements regarding the `Map` implementation, there's no need to use a version of Collector `toMap()` which expects a *mapFactory*.

Instead, use *three-args* version, which expects only functions mapping keys/values and resolving duplicates, namely: *keyMapper*, *valueMapper* and a *mergeFunction* [`toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper, mergeFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)).

Also, you have messed with the order of arguments in the *mergeFunction*. The previously associated Value comes first, i.e. `oldValue` then `newValue` (*not the opposite, although in this case it has no impact on the result since mergeFunction only performs addition of* `BigDecimal` *values*). And as *@Holger* has pointed out in the comments, there's no need to perform null-check unless *valueMapper* function can produce `null`.

```
(oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue.add(newValue)
```

Which can be translated into a Method reference:

```
BigDecimal::add
```

That's how `collect()` operation might look like in this case:

```
.collect(Collectors.toMap(
    position -> new PositionKey(
        position.getAssetId(),
        position.geCurrencyId()
    ),
    Position::geValue,
    BigDecimal::add
))
```

And you would be provided with the default general purpose implementation of the `Map` interface by default, which is for now `HashMap` (*if there would be another general purpose implementation which come as a recommended replacement of* `HashMap` *you'll get it for free without changing the code*). Hence, providing `HashMap::new` as a *mapFactory* is frankly pointless.

A use case for the *four-args* version of `toMap()` expecting a *mapFactory* would be a situation when you need a special purpose `Map` implementation, like `EnumMap`, `TreeMap`, `LinkedHashMap`, etc.

Comment: @Holger Right, missed that map's Values are of type `BidDecimal`. Fixed the answer.

Comment: By the way, assuming `(oldValue, newValue) -> …` for a merge function is only valid when calling `Map.merge` manually. In case of the `toMap` collector, both arguments might be the result of a previous merge function evaluation (e.g. when evaluating in parallel).

Comment: As I can see, `toMap()` [internally uses `Map.merge()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#l317) and since this collector is ordered the partial results from different threads should be merged according to the initial order of the portions of data these threads received (if the stream is ordered). So why can't we expect that `(l, r) -> l` would preserve the Value produced from the earlier stream element (i.e. `l` was placed in the stream before `r`) ?

Comment: When you have only two elements, the `(l, r) -> …` merge function can safely assume that `l` is the first and `r` is the second element. [But that doesn’t work for three or more elements](https://tio.run/##dVDJasMwEL37KwadJOyIplcngTbQW045lh5UL0GJLBlpHBpCvt0dWy5Z2g5IT5p5b7a9OqrZvjz0vW5a5xH25JAdaiPrzhaonZVv0yNPfnEC@ko1cu2MqQp0PvzP2Y6QJ0nbfRpdQGFUCLBR2sI5AbLJH1AhwdHpEhqKchJqu3v/AOV3QUzkwWrnubYIGpbwlBMs4JkgTW9Jg8XSi5hoBbEhEkW/dDVnLywD9jpcaybyO7WuOVVYwlxcldNMrfKKJjf8QTKFi7gWfl2PRLdRLf@C2QrmGfxsVuqysqjxxEV2lygaNxl4MWjOsD0FrKjnDmVL46CxnDWV39FkwCAFQ4eBsuX48yIHX2Hn7RjwOVzEQ69/JLxhXJJ4X5K@/wY)

Comment: @Holger Thanks, so both `l` and `r` might be produced by the mergeFunction, and the order of their processing would reflect the ordering of equal keys (elements from which identical keys were generated).

Comment: The order still reflects the encounter order; that’s why it is enough when the function is associative and it is not required to be commutative, e.g. `String::concat` will produce the correct final result.

Answer (score 2):

simple! replace `() -> map` with either `() -> new HashMap<>()` or `HashMap::new`